# Laravel Eloquent Where With

Tags: php, laravel

```
<?php

namespace App\Services\v1;

use Validator;

use App\Group;
use App\GroupPrivacy;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;

class GroupService {

    protected $supportedIncludes = [
        'groupCases' => 'group_cases',
        'groupUsers'  => 'group_users'
    ];

    protected $clauseProperties = [
        'visibility'
    ];

    public function getGroups($parameters) {

        if (empty($parameters)) {
            return $this->filterGroups(Group::all());
        }

        $withKeys = $this->getWithKeys($parameters);
        $whereClauses = $this->getWhereClause($parameters);

        return Group::with($withKeys)->where($whereClauses)->get();

    }

    protected function getWithKeys($parameters) {
        $withKeys = [];

        if (isset($parameters['include'])) {
            $includeParams = explode(',', $parameters['include']);
            $includes = array_intersect($this->supportedIncludes, $includeParams);
            $withKeys = array_keys($includes);
        }

        $withKeys[] = 'groupPrivacy';

        return $withKeys;
    }

    protected function getWhereClause($parameters) {
        $clause = [];

        foreach ($this->clauseProperties as $prop) {
            if (in_array($prop, array_keys($parameters))) {
                $clause[$prop] = $parameters[$prop];
            }
        }

        return $clause;
    }


}
```

Hello,

I want to get some data from table with conditions.

My request : /api/v1/groups?include=&visibility=0

I am trying to get groups which has visibility is 0. But visibility column in group_privacy table. So i made a relation between them :

GroupPrivacy Model :

```
class GroupPrivacy extends Model {

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'visibility',
        'notification'
    ];

    public function groups() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Group', 'group_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

Group Model :

```
class Group extends Model {

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id',
        'group_category_id',
        'name',
        'description',
        'img_path'
    ];

    public function groupPrivacy() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\GroupPrivacy', 'group_id', 'id');
    }

    public function users() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

Also i added groupPrivacy in my `$withKeys` array automatically...

But it gives an error :

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'visibility' in
>   'where clause' (SQL: select * from `groups` where (`visibility` = 0))

This error true but how can i say "LOOK IN GROUP_PRIVACY TABLE, YOU HACKIN IDIOT!!" ?

**ps. Laravel 5.3**

Comment: it seems like the relation between two tables is not there. Which line is the cause of the error?

Comment: `whereHas` to query relation.

Comment: if i write user_id instead of visibility, it works. Because user_id in groups table but visibility in group_privacies. with() clause works but where() clause does not work if the where parameter in with() 's tables..

Comment: The where only works on the table of the model, for relationships you can filter using `with("groupPrivacy" => function ($query) { $query->where("visibility",0); })`

Comment: @apokryfos but i don't which parameter will send.

Comment: @ÖzgünÜNLÜ You can check the input to figure it out and pass the one that you need to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do something like

```
$group = Group::whereHas('groupPrivacy', function($q){
    $q->where('visibility ', '=', 0);
})
```

Comment: i don't which parameter will send. It is REST API